# Randomly generate date & time in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, random, stl

Can anyone please suggest/provide C++ code to generate random date (more precisely date & time or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS),  between today and say 5 years back. Should be fine if it is based on uniform distribution.

Comment: As this is a very specific question, please explain where you got stuck when first attempting a solution yourself.

Comment: Generate a random number for number of seconds between 0 and 5 years, and add it to the date 5 years ago.

Comment: No, we can't provide code. First show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some would probably argue that the following is "more C than C++", but you can still give it a try...

---

**First, define the maximum number of seconds that you want to "go back to":**

```
#define MAX_NUM_OF_SECONDS (5*365*24*60*60) // number of seconds in 5 years
```

In order to ensure uniform distribution, this number should **not** be larger than `RAND_MAX*RAND_MAX`.

---

**Then, implement a function that returns a Time/Date structure with random contents:**

```
struct tm* GetTimeAndDate()
{
    unsigned int now_seconds  = (unsigned int)time(NULL);
    unsigned int rand_seconds = (rand()*rand())%(MAX_NUM_OF_SECONDS+1);
    time_t       rand_time    = (time_t)(now_seconds-rand_seconds);
    return localtime(&rand_time);
}
```

If you're working on a multi-threaded application, then please note that this function is **not** thread safe.

---

**Finally, seed the RNG before you start using it (e.g, at the beginning of your program):**

```
int main()
{
    ...
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, +barak manos and +clcto, that pretty much the answer of my question, can use stl distribution. Thanks again

Comment: @SKhan: You should also make sure that your definition for `MAX_NUM_OF_SECONDS` is not larger than `RAND_MAX*RAND_MAX` (which is usually equal to 32767*32767). I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Your seconds in 5 years are off by between `86400` and `172801`.

Comment: @Yakk: Thank you. That is indeed a very good reason to down-vote me on this answer, whose purpose is to provide OP with a general template for his or her question (leaving him or her to do the math on the "time to go back to")!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you know your begin date and end date, you can, using strptime(), convert those dates to time_t which are usually long integers. Given those long integers, you should be able to then create a random integer between them. Convert that long integer back to a date/time string using strftime().

Comment: `strptime` is not standard C++; it's part of Posix.